# How can I get bazel 0.26 (or older) for CentOS?

Tags: centos, bazel

I need to compile Tensorflow from source using Bazel. As doing so on Ubuntu and then using it on CentOS does not seem to work properly, I want to build tensorflow from source directly on CentOS. The official Bazel homepage says: "The Bazel team does not provide official packages for Fedora and CentOS. Vincent Batts (@vbatts) generously maintains unofficial packages on Fedora COPR." However there I only find the .repo files for 0.27, which does not support the build process for Tensorflow. Is there a way to get 0.26.1 or older for CentOS?

Answer (score 3):

You can download 0.26.0 bazel using the link below, https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.26.0/bazel-0.26.0-installer-linux-x86_64.sh

Comment: And generally all the older releases would still be listed on the release page: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases