# How to uninstall bazel 0.29.0 in order to install 0.26.1 because of tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, redhat, bazel

I am using Redhat 7.3. I need to install tensorflow for that I already installed bazel 0.29.0 and when I wanted to configure tensorflow it requires bazel 0.26.1. Thats why i tried to uninstall bazel 0.29.0 but was not able to do it. I am new in Redhat community , could you please show me a way how to solve this problem ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to be essentially the same question as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56737606/how-can-i-get-bazel-0-26-or-older-for-centos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For newer versions `2.1.1`, I executed the following

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/bazel /etc/bazelrc /usr/lib/bazel
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
rm $HOME/.cache/bazel
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/bazel /etc/bazelrc /usr/local/lib/bazel
```

Worked for me. I needed to reinstall bazel

Comment: Thank you solved the problem, I install bazel 0.26.1 and deactivated the bazel 0.29.0

Answer (score 2):

For  windows  user

```
choco uninstall bazel --yes
```